# NodeJS child_process: different results when using spawn and console

Tags: node.js, linux, png, child-process, pngquant

I'm trying to compress an image with `pngquant`. Here is the code:

```
  let output = '';
  const quant = cp.spawn('pngquant', ['256', '--speed', '10'], {
    stdio: [null, null, 'ignore'],
  });

  quant.stdout.on('data', data => output += data);

  quant.on('close', () => {
    fs.writeFileSync('image.png', output);
    fs.writeFileSync('image_original.png', image);
    process.exit(0);
  });

  quant.stdin.write(image);
```

`image` is a `Buffer` with pure PNG data.
The code works, however, for some reason, it generates incorrect PNG. Not only that, but also it's size is more than original's.

When I execute this from the terminal, I get excellent output file:

```
pngquant 256 --speed 10 < image_original.png > image.png
```

I have no idea of what's going on; the data in output file seems pretty PNG-ish.

**EDIT**: I have managed to make it work:

```
let output = [];

quant.stdout.on('data', data => output.push(data));
quant.stdin.write(image);

quant.on('close', () => {
  const image = Buffer.concat(output);

  fs.writeFileSync('image.png', image);
});
```

I assume that is related to how strings are represented in the NodeJS. Would be happy to get some explanation.

Comment: Where does `image` come from?

Comment: @jfriend00 it comes from the `stdin` of the main process; the data is correct because I also save that as a PNG file.

Comment: So, you're  waiting until you've gotten all the data from `stdin` before you execute any of this code?

Comment: Yes. I managed to make it work, see the edit.

Comment: Treating it as a string probably assumes utf8 encoding which causes problems with pure binary data.  As you discovered, you use Buffers for binary data.  FYI, you just pipe the data directly to a file.  You don't have to accumulate it all before writing it.

Comment: The thing is that I don't need to store the data in a file. That was just an example.

Comment: FYI, you should not a solution into the question here on Stackoverflow.  Instead, you should write your own answer and put the solution in the answer.